# how to make each drop down menu align according to the button hovered over

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I am new to coding and have managed to make a navbar with the first two buttons as dropdown menus. However, I have noticed that while hovering over the first button works fine, when I hover over the second dropdown button, the dropdown menu displays directly under the first button, whilst displaying the right information. [Here](http://file:///C:/Users/Mafe%20Cardozo/Documents/Code%20Practice/Introduction%20to%20JavaScript/Third%20Attempt.html) is a photo to explain what I mean.

And here is my code, what I have tried to do here is to reuse all the code I have written for the first dropdown menu and then added a class to the second dropdown to slightly alter what is necessary to make the menu align to the second dropdown button:

```css
#NavBar {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}

#NavBar ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height:25px;
}

#NavBar ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 25%;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 background-color: #eecbff;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.DropBtn {
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 25px;
 border: 0;
 background-color: #eecbff;
}

.DropBtn:hover {
 background-color: #ffd4e5;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

.Dropdown {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

.DropContent {
 display: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #ffd4e5;
 width: 25%;
 top: 31px;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}

.Dropdown:hover .DropContent {
 display: block;
 border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}

.DropContent a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 color: black;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

.Dropdown:hover .DropBtn {
 background-color: #ffd4e5;
 border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}

.DropContent a:hover {
 background-color: #feffa3;
 border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}

.Second .DropContent{
 position: absolute;
 left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="NavBar">
 <ul>
  <div class="Dropdown">
  <li><button class="DropBtn">Dropdown 1</button></li>
   <div class="DropContent">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Dropdown">
  <li><button class="DropBtn Second" >Dropdown 2</button></li>
   <div class="DropContent">
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <li><button class="DropBtn">Dropdown 3</button></li>
  <li><button class="DropBtn">Dropdown 4</button></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I'm very sorry if my code is very long winded, I am sure there are parts that aren't even necessary, any tips or comments about my code in general would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap your list item in a div. Using your current styles, I would drop the `<div class="Dropdown">` and just apply that class to the list item specifically. If you do this, your dropdown will work as intended. See my edited HTML below.

I imagine the reason for this is, your Dropdown div doesn't really have a width or height, because its children are either floated or positioned absolutely. It's also unnecessary to do this,  because the list item itself is perfectly capable of being a parent for your dropdown content, and it already has the positioning that you need.

Changes made: Wrapped the .DropContent div inside the li tag with the button. Removed the parent .Dropdown div and added the .Dropdown class to the li.

```
<div id="NavBar">
    <ul>
        <li class="Dropdown">
            <button class="DropBtn">Dropdown 1</button>
            <div class="DropContent">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="Dropdown">
            <button class="DropBtn" >Dropdown 2</button>
            <div class="DropContent">
                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                <a href="#">Link 6</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><button class="DropBtn">Dropdown 3</button></li>
        <li><button class="DropBtn">Dropdown 4</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Edited formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, works perfectly now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your `DropContent` divs inside of the correspondent `<li>` tag, like the example bellow:

```
<div class="Dropdown">
  <li>
    <button class="DropBtn Second">Dropdown 2</button>
    <div class="DropContent">
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```